# How can I change AutoTextSize (Maximum & Minimum)

Tags: java, android

How can I change AutoTextSize (Maximum & Minimum) by java code in Android Studio.

```
    TextView versesText;
    versesText = findViewById(R.id.VersesArabicTashkeel);
    versesText.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration(5, 25 ,1,1);
    //versesText.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration(5, 25 ,0,0);
```

I want to set the Max to 25 and the Min to 5 and in other code I need to change the max to 20 and min to 5

app crashing with previous code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet you used `versesText.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration(5, 25, 1, 1);` is totally wrong. Refer to the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview) for correct usage of it. The documentation clearly states that:

> define a range of text sizes and a dimension programmatically through the support library, call the `TextViewCompat.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration(int autoSizeMinTextSize, int autoSizeMaxTextSize, int autoSizeStepGranularity, int unit)` method. Provide the maximum value, the minimum value, the granularity value, and any TypedValue dimension unit.

So, you should've used something like below:

```
TextViewCompat.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration(5, 25, 1, 1);
```

Additionally, check for following things if you haven't included them already:

> The Support Library 26.0 provides full support to the auto sizing TextView feature on devices running Android versions prior to Android 8.0 (API level 26).

As Support Library 26 has now been moved to Google’s maven repository,
include this in your project level `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {

   repositories {
       google()
   }
   ....
}
```

And to add the support library in your app level build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
   ....
   implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.2'

}
```